# Lighttpd - rewrite request when 404 error

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd, http-status-code-404

I have question if it is possible do run mod_rewrite rule when 404 error occurs. Example:

Request: http://domain.com/files/img/file.jpg

If there is no **/files/file.jpg**, then Lightttpd should rewrite request to file **/files2/img/file.jpg**

How to do that in lighttpd/mod_rewrite conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use mod_magnet and write simple [lua](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/AbsoLUAtion) script to do this job.

```
# lua redirect example
# match URI for /files
if (string.match(lighty.env["uri.path"], "^/files")) then
  # test file existence with stat()
  if (not lighty.stat(lighty.env["physical.path"])) then
    lighty.env["physical.path"] = lighty.env["physical.doc-root"] .. "/files2/img/file.jpg"
  end
end
```

More examples in link above.